# Community Poll: What sect or school of Hinduism do you believe in?

Tags: discussion, community

I often post questions about obscure sects of Hinduism, and I'm unsure of whether we have any members of those sects on the site.  So I thought it would be helpful to myself and others to create a poll to identify what sects of Hinduism are represented in our community.

You can participate in the poll by upvoting the answer corresponding to your sect.  And if you want, you can post a comment identifying yourself so people know what members they can consult about a particular sect of Hinduism.
Kindly **don't** downvote any of the answers, since that would obscure the numbers.

You can select either the sect of Hinduism your family follows, or the one you personally believe in.

Comment: There is a whole big sect of various goddesses (like Vaishno Devi, Kaali maata, Durga maa, Amba maa, Maa Bhairavi, ...). Some call it [Mataji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mataji) sect. BTW, this Qn could have been better in the main site.

Comment: @iammilind I think it's better on Meta since it's less about Hinduism as such and more about the community.

Comment: This question encouraged me to look for the information about all major Sampradaya!

Comment: I think this is the first ever poll on the site! :)

Comment: Downvoted. What do u mean by sects to start with? What about millions of devotees of Ganesha?  Are  they not Hindus or don't they belong to the Ganapatya Sect. ? What about devotees of Surya and Karthikeya? 99% of Hindus do not know about these so called sects but they identify themselves as devotees of one or the other Hidu Deities. And the polls also did not include the Shakta which is of course one the major Hindu sects.!!

Comment: @Rickross It's just a fun community poll.  In any case I included the options "I'm a Hindu but I don't identify myself with a particular sect or school of Hinduism." and "I belong to some other sect or school of Hinduism not listed."

Comment: @Rickross Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57984/discussion-between-keshav-srinivasan-and-rickross).

Comment: This promotes profiling. Must be deleted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is prejudicial and promotes profiling.

Comment: Mods- why are you declining legit flags?

Comment: What am I called if I feel a lot of love towards Shivji, Ramji, Agni Deva and Shani Deva and Lord Yama. I also believe that Shaiva, Vaishnava and Shaktas, all can get Moksha, and believe in Vedas. I consider all living beings my brothers and sisters and pray for my moksha, for the happiness of all creatures, and some other material desires. What is my sect called?

Comment: @Shashwat You can select “I'm a Hindu but I don't identify myself with a particular sect or school of Hinduism.”  In any case I’m a Sri Vaishnava, and I believe that Vaishnavas, Shaivas, and Shaktas can get Moksha, but in the case of Shaivas and Shaktas they can get Moksha by getting reborn as Vaishnavas.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan aren't there Shaiva texts saying that by praying to Shiva, one can get moksha? Do you consider Shaiva texts interpolated or unauthentic?

Comment: @Shashwat I think Shaivite texts are authentic, it’s just that they’re Tamasic.  A Tamasic person reads Tamasic Puranas and thereby in subsequent births becomes Rajasic.  Then a Rajasic person reads Rajasic Puranas and thereby in subsequent births becomes Sattvic.  And then once he becomes Sattvic he can do either Bhakti Yoga or Sharanagati to Vishnu and thereby he attains Moksha.

Answer (score 9):

I'm a Hindu but I don't identify myself with a particular sect or school of Hinduism.

Answer (score 8):

I'm an [Advaitin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advaita_Vedanta).

Comment: I may not exactly be an Advaitin.. but I'm very close to Advaita philosophy...

Comment: Same as @Tezz. Shakta by birth but very close to Shankara Advaita.

Comment: @TheDestroyer This is the first I have heard of "shakta by birth". Can you please elaborate.

Comment: @moonstar2001 what i meant is, our Kula Devata is Devi. But i don't strongly identify myself with any sect but philosophically close to Shankara Advaita.

Answer (score 8):

I'm a [Sri Vaishnava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sri_Vaishnavism).

Comment: Sri Vaishnava with Vadakalai inclination...

Comment: I'm a Sri Vaishnava whose Dad is a Thenkalai and whose Mom is a Vadakalai, so I'm a Thenkalai by birth but my beliefs lean more to the Vadakalai side.

Comment: Adiyen Ramanuja Dasan!

Comment: @anuvaramban Adien Ramanuja Dasan Namo Narayanaya! :D

Answer (score 2):

I'm a [Gaudiya Vaishnava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaudiya_Vaishnavism).

Comment: Who are the GVs in this site? I don't see any active member now a days.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a follower of Vallabhacharya's [Pushtimarga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushtimarg) sect.

Comment: Am I the only 1? Thanks for including this BTW.

Comment: @iammilind No, you're not the only one.  Mr. Alien and Krishn Shweta are also.

Comment: @iammilind I'm Lord Krishna's follower. But I'm not familiar with Vallabacharya's works, so I didn't cast my vote :)

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58000/discussion-on-answer-by-keshav-srinivasan-community-poll-what-sect-or-school-of).

Answer (score 1):

I'm a [Shaiva Siddhantin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaiva_Siddhanta).

Comment: I am curious, who is the Shaiva Siddhantin here?

Comment: @Ambi That is captured by Shaiva Siddhantin.

Comment: Oh lol... Sorry Now I understand what you were asking for People who were shaiva siddhantins. Got it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a [Madhwa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madhvacharya).

Answer (score 1):

I'm a [Kashmiri Shaivite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kashmir_Shaivism).

Answer (score 1):

I belong to some other sect or school of Hinduism not listed. (You can specify which in the comments if you want.)

Comment: I'm a Ramanandi Vaishnava.

Comment: Smartha-vaishnava (not an advaitin)

Comment: I'm a nimbArkin (dvaitadvaita)

Answer (score 1):

I belong to a non-Hindu religion.  (You can specify which in the comments if you want.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm an [atheist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atheism) or [agnostic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agnosticism).

Comment: Why do you need atheists here?

Comment: @Yogi Because this is a poll of the community as a whole, and some members of the community are atheists, agnostics, or members of other religions.

Comment: wouldn't astika/nastika distinction be more relevant as well to include in the H.SE context, as a separate answer perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

I belong to the [Swaminarayan sect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swaminarayan_Sampraday).

Answer (score 0):

I'm a [Shakta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaktism).

Comment: No one upvoted? That's odd.