# How to find out the time when a vote has been cast here on meta?

Tags: support, votes

Is there a way of knowing when a vote has been cast here on Meta?

In Main, we can easily know the time, when votes are cast, from the reputation tab.

But what's the method here? Can't seem to find it.

........................................................................

For example let's take [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/21830/4732) question. Right now it has four upvotes and zero downvote. We can know when these votes were cast by the following method:

Go, to [OP's (share knowledge) activity tab and then to reputation tab](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/12393/share-knowledge?tab=reputation) and then expand.

[image]

Now, if we are applying this method to a post which is a lot older than the example post, then it will consume some time all right but still finding the time is possible.

But, this method does not work for posts made here on Meta.

Comment: Are you talking about when vote cased by you or for you only or other users?

Comment: Have you tried [timeline](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/988/timeline)?

Comment: @Pandya Yes generally. In Main i can know, if i want to, when a post has been up or down voted be it my post or someone else's. In the same way i want a method for meta. No i never tried timeline. If that's the method then you should post an answer.

Comment: @Rickross Some may feel difficult to understand the question. You can add screenshot of "rep tab"  of main to make it clear

Comment: @TheDestroyer Is it clear now? i have updated the Q.

Comment: @Rickross Ok. it is clear now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *time* of the votes isn't available, but the *date* is, via the timeline feature, which is rather hidden by itself. Consider the following Meta question:

[Community Poll: What sect or school of Hinduism do you believe in?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/842/7988)

From the URL, it can be seen that the ID of the question is 842, so the timeline can be found here: https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/842/timeline

[image: timeline for user without established user privilege]

This gives a summary of the score (upvotes minus downvotes) per day for a user without [Established User](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) privilege, but for users with the Established User privilege, the upvotes and downvotes will be shown separately. For a user with access to [moderator tools](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), time of deleted answers is also visible along with separate vote count.

[image: Timeline for a user with mod tools]

Alternatively, you can use a SEDE query like [this one](http://data.stackexchange.com/hinduismme/query/747658/up-and-downvotes-on-a-specific-post?PostId=842). Note that SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It is enough for me to know the day on which the votes were cast.

Comment: @Rickross Btw, timeline is one the the [hidden features of StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64522/260388)!

Comment: @Glorifindel, I added an image for a 2k user and modified a sentence. Hope you don't mind the modification.

Comment: @NogShine thanks!

Comment: Okay @Pandya noted that.